# How to fix new stdClass error

Tags: php, stdclass

I am trying to understand the `new stdClass` in terms of sending data to a function, I've created the following code and I'll get an error that's saying `Warning: Creating default object from empty value`, however, still I get the json data as well. How to fix the error and why I am getting it?

```
$send = new stdClass();
$send->user->id = '12121212121';
$send->message->attachment->type = 'file';
$send->message->attachment->image = 'png';
$res = process($send);

function process($send){
    $data = json_encode($send);
    print_r($data);
}
```

Result is looks like this and there is an error above below result as I mentioned it:

`{"user":{"id":"12121212121"},"message":{"attachment":{"type":"file","image":"png"}}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create stdClass for each reference like this

```
$send = new stdClass();
$send->user=new stdClass();
$send->user->id = '12121212121';
$send->message=new stdClass();
$send->message->attachment=new stdClass();
$send->message->attachment->type = 'file';
$send->message->attachment->image = 'png';
$res = process($send);

function process($send){
    $data = json_encode($send);
    print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is works but why we have to create stdClass for each one of them?, Why a single one can't do the job? Please explain, Thanks

Comment: example $send is an object of stdClass then user is a property not an object of stdClass so to make user as object again we have to recursively use stdClass